# Firebase-Firestore structuring

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design

Imagine I have multiple companies, which each have multiple employees, multiple vehicles, routes, departures, captured damages and assignments(who has to drive a tour).

How should I structure my Firestore to have it simple and with an overview? The current structure looks a bit like this:

I have multiple collections, which hold all the different companies, all the vehicles, all the employees and so on...

```
- employees:
  - employyeDocuments
    - field with companyID (reference to the company document)
    - field with employeeID (the uid of that employee, used for identification)
- companies:
  - companyDocuments
    - array of all the vehicles (each element is a reference to a vehicle in the vehicle collection)
- assignments:
  - assignmentDocuments
    - field with employeeID
    - field with companyID
    - field with vehicleID
    - field with routeID (all IDs are document references to the according documents)
- routes:
  - routeDocuments
    - information about the route, waypoints, delivery options... (but NO companyID or employeeID, since that route should be reused and is assigned to an employee in assignments)
- damages:
  - damageDocuments
    - any recorded damages
```

There are more collections and documents, but they all follow similar rules, so they don't need to be addressed here. My question is now: Is there any better way to structure this to make it easier to read and avoid accidentally mixing up companies or employees? Or is the approach I use the right one? I am sorrowed about me losing the overview or the database becoming a complete mess.

Education would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, it looks like your structure appears sound but this may be a "many to many" situation and can be addressed in several ways. from experience, keeping it simple but modular has always been key.

Keeping a document with the document name being the UID for that entity is a common tried and tested solution.
simply referencing an id as the field property, an array of id's for the employees in the company, etc.

You should also manage a master employee document by merging all current employee documents into a master document for employers or HR and simply update it with a query for any new employees who may not be on the list.

This restful approach can help reduce maintenance needs and improve performance overall.

Comment: Thank you very much! So it would be a better approach to have all the employees listed in an array under the company document, than to have each employee reference their belonging company in their own document?

Comment: sounds ideal, having documents for users under others is a good way of adding association for that user. the downside is that user cannot be in multiple employers at the same time if that is a desired effect

Comment: If I were to change the assignment structure, would it be better to have the company, employee, route and vehicles as a document reference or should I simply store the document (or employee) ID?

Comment: a document reference for information that isn't often needed, otherwise duplicate data where it's needed. a subcollection for different types of entities, cars, employee's etc. you may want a car to mention it is on a route ID, but not duplicate the route into it but keep a master document for all routes that all cars can reference, etc - but this is getting into more opinion based speculation.